# Why I don't see any messages of megaRAID initialization?

Tags: hardware-raid, megaraid

I have existing win10 system installed on SSD drive. I've got a MegaRAID card and want to add a RAID5 storage to my system.

My motherboard is asrock z68 extreme3 gen3. I've installed the card into second x16 PCI-e. But when I turn the system on - I don't see any signs of megaRAID initialization. The card itself seems powered, blinking and heating.

I have another, brand new AMD system, with no OS installed yet - I put the card there and it initializes as expected before the main BIOS.

Why the behavior is different? Does it mean my ASROCK mb isn't compatible, or I need to change smth in its BIOS so RAID controller will start to initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was a video card in the main x16 slot. Most of MBs in this case give x16 to the video card leaving only x4 to the second slot. It's possible that it's a MB issue, I found some references where people had troubles installing RAID into second PCIex16 even without videocard.

The solution was to switch video card and RAID-controller, so now it is forced to be x8 + x8. The MegaRAID initializes as expected. There might be 1-4% drop in video performance, which is OK :)

Comment: That's the controllers fault then, it should have gracefully degraded to PCIe 4x.

Comment: Or it could be a MB problem, I saw a thread where ASrock user described a case when RAIDcontroller refused to work in the second slot no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Some BIOS just hide these messages, and some times you need to go into the advanced part of the BIOS, and tweak a few settings.  Since, I can't see you BIOS I can't tell you what your manufacturer calls it.

Sometimes capturing Interrupt 13 fixes it, and sometimes it is another setting.

Most cards have windows management software, and you just use that to control them.

Comment: Could you be more specific given the MB model and the controller vendor? I've tried MegaRaid Storage Management, it's looking for remote servers using my local IP and never find anything.

Comment: If I can get a manual from ASROCK.com with pictures of the BIOS in it, I might be able to help, but not all manuals include all BIOS screen.  You can also try another PCIe slot.